# Remove parent <td> in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following table structure:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <th width="70%">File</th>
    <th width="15%">Size</th>
    <th width="15%">Delete</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Mon fichier</td>
     <td>3 kB</td>
     <td><a href="#" class="deleteFile" id="007"> Delete </a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$('.deleteFile').click(function(){
  if (confirm("Delete ?")){
    $imagefile = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
    ...
```

How can I remove/hide the `<tr>` containing my link?

Comment: Grr.. I can't accept all you replies... :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TR` is the `ancestor` of the `anchor tag` in your situation, So use `.closest()` to get the desired result.

Try,

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

Your code,

```
$('.deleteFile').click(function(){
  if (confirm("Delete ?")){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove(); //removing the TR
    $imagefile = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Use closest() to get the ancestor of element and the use hide() or remove()

To hide

```
$(this).closest('tr').hide();
```

To remove

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Write:

```
$('.deleteFile').click(function(){
    if (confirm("Delete ?")){
        $imagefile = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).closest("tr").remove(); 
//        $(this).closest("tr").hide(); 
    }
});
```